# Xcode cocoa pods pod install Sentry causes " Module 'Sentry' not found"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I follow the guide on their home page.
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/apple/guides/ios/

I call pod deintegrate and then after I call pod install.
The error appears immediately after I call pod install and I have no idea why.
The Library Sentry.Framework is in Link Binary With Libraries under build Phases in my target app.

I have tried looking through SO for similar issues, but none actually solve the issue for me.

I have tried to clean build, added $(inherited) to other linker flags and adding path to framework search path($(PROJECT_DIR/Pods/Sentry) I don't know whether this is the correct way to do it). None of the mentioned solved the issue.

Any leads to what could be wrong would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

**platform :ios, '9.0'**

**use_frameworks!**

**target 'yourApp' do**

**pod 'Sentry', :git => 'https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cocoa.git', :tag => '7.2.2'**

**end**

The above is my Pod File

Comment: It would help grately if you would provide your Podfile source in this post.

Comment: Did you change `yourApp` to the name of your app?

Comment: also check that you do infact want iOS 9.0 as your minimum. That is very old and out of date

Comment: I have changed the "YourApp" to the name of my own. I also have changed the IOS 9.0 to 9.1. Thats what the company wants. Besides that even when running the app it does still say the same error

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the module import `@import` mapped by `.modulemap`, could you add as declarative framework library `#import`.

Module import:

```objectivec
@import Sentry;
```

Framework import:

```objectivec
#import <Sentry/Sentry.h>
```